# salt-minion dropping connection to master

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to salt and have setup a master with 2 remote minions. All works perfectly well until after some time the master loses the connections from the minions. I think the TCP connection is getting drop by something in the salt stack. Debug shows nothing re connections being lost on either master or minion.

Is there a config setting to force the minions to reconnect?

```
Minion Report:

Salt Version:
           Salt: 2017.7.4

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.5.5
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.12
          PyZMQ: 17.0.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.6

System Versions:
           dist: debian 9.1 
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: armv6l
        release: 4.9.59+
         system: Linux
        version: debian 9.1 


Master report:

Salt Version:
           Salt: 2017.7.4

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.10
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.5.5
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.12
          PyZMQ: 17.0.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.6

System Versions:
           dist: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.4.0-104-generic
         system: Linux
        version: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
```

salt-minion log after connection lost on master:

```
2018-03-02 09:35:27,072 [salt.utils.verify:525 ][WARNING ][10481] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
2018-03-02 09:35:28,973 [py.warnings      :69  ][WARNING ][10481] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/minion.py:802: DeprecationWarning: 
zmq.eventloop.ioloop is deprecated in pyzmq 17. pyzmq now works with default tornado and asyncio eventloops.
  zmq.eventloop.ioloop.install()
```

salt-master log (UTC)

```
2018-03-01 22:57:03,312 [py.warnings      :69  ][WARNING ][97734] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/salt/utils/async.py:56: DeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.ioloop is deprecated in pyzmq 17. pyzmq now w
orks with default tornado and asyncio eventloops.
  self.io_loop = LOOP_CLASS()
```

Comment: Please provide logs from the minions located in `/var/log/salt/minion`. The answer is most likely in there, as the minion is responsible to connect itself to the master. Contents of the master log may also be interesting. `/var/log/salt/master`.

Comment: Thanks dahrens, I have updated with log info.